# Down voting with no comment

Tags: discussion, status-completed

Some people downvote a question or an answer but don't comment on what's wrong with it. This is problematic. Either the downvoter is wrong or the downvoted answer is wrong and there is no way to tell which is true, even in principle, without an argument let alone fix any problems. Would there be a way to require a comment in order to downvote it and would that be desirable?

Comment: No, and demanding down voters out themselves is a lot more problematic to my mind than anonymous downvoting, which is a very intentional functionality of the system

Comment: In most cases it's easy to tell whether the downvote was fair or not. When it's not fair, someone will notice it and upvote to balance things things out. If it hasn't been noticed, just leave a comment in the chat (or here?). Looking briefly over your answers, I think you could benefit by not making too many strong claims (e.g. "induction is impossible"). Even if you go on to qualify such a claim, not many read or are able to follow to the end. But again, I only looked briefly at your answers and there may be stylistic, pedagogic or other changes you can make to make them more agreeable.

Comment: i think, when we downvote without comments - we are giving an answerer our disaproval, but without a tip how to improve. This can cause frustration and reduce the (already low) number number of active people in community.

Answer (score 7):

This has been addressed many times, the bottom line is that the admins feel the current system is the best option and mods of individual sites have no power to change things like this. At best it could be made as a "community best practice" if there is total consensus, but I doubt we'd ever get that.

META SE: [So annoyed with no-comment, vindictive downvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22934/so-annoyed-with-no-comment-vindictive-downvoting)

META SE: [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-downvotes)

HERE: [Should we explain downvotes?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/should-we-explain-downvotes)