# Why was my answer downvoted?

Tags: discussion, answers

The answer [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/59997/what-is-the-distinction-between-experimental-philosophy-and-anthropology)

Unlike the other (upvoted) answer (which I commented on) it demonstrates no fallacious reasoning, nor is it rhetorically presented. Instead, it is clearly worded, referenced, worked out, and correct.

I mind less when people vote down questions, whereas at this point the voter/s are just spreading disinformation. I'm just asking for an explanation, not demanding one

Comment: Your answer looks fine to me. But if you want an explanation for each and every down vote you'll never get one. Everyone gets downvotes they don't think are warranted. That's just part of Stack Exchange.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should we explain downvotes?](https://philosophy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/485/should-we-explain-downvotes)

Comment: I don't hesitate to downvote when, as the message pop-up when you pass the mouse over the down-vote arrow, _the answer is not useful_. But beforehand I always tend to _consider adding a comment if (I) think this post can be improved._. I hope (but can't be sure) everyone follows these rules. As a result maybe your answer wasn't useful to some readers? I hope they consider explain to you why.

Comment: @ThePassenger i guess they just disagreed with the conclusion. hmm

Answer (score 3):

I did not down vote your answer, but I want to point out you received two up votes and one down vote as of this writing. So you have a net positive number of votes.

It is good to ask oneself how one might improve an answer if one receives a total of 0 or fewer votes. What that means is *for whatever reasons* the current social mood did not favor the post. Social mood changes, but getting the low votes should prompt one to ask: *How might the post be improved?*

@Curiousdannii made a good observation when editing your answer:

> Please don't link random words in quotes to their sources - it makes it look like the links were part of what you were quoting. Please give a citation with author/title, and link those to the source pages.

I would suggest going beyond even that and think of any link as *transitory*. It is only a temporary convenience to the reader. Furthermore, it is not a citation.

For any quote, you should make sure that enough information about whatever you have quoted appears somewhere in the post, before, after or at the end, in case the link breaks. This gives credit to the authors of the quote. I also use Google Scholar to format the reference or if the cite has a "how to cite" link, I use that.

I find down voting answers to be less damaging to the poster than down voting a question. If an answer receives too many down votes it can be deleted more easily than if a question has been down voted that has been answered.